# Check all compile errors

Tags: vba

I have inherited a fairly large vba program that was built without *Option Explicit* turned on.

I've added this to the code and am working through the compile errors (Debug > Compile ...)
All issues I've come across so far are variables that are not declared

```
Compile error:
Variable not defined
```

My issue is that the compiler only displays one error at at time.
Is there a way to display all compile errors in a single view?

Comment: i do not think that the compiler proceeds after it finds an error.  it would be pointless .... there may be a plugin that does the checking .... there has been a lot of mentions of `rubberduck` ... it may or may  not have that ability ....  supported by Mat's Mug    https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck

Comment: Nope. Maybe the http://rubberduckvba.com Code Inspections can help a bit

Comment: The VBA compiler stops at the first error it encounters, so there isn't more than one error at a time. You can't ask about possible third-party solutions here, because it violates the site guidelines according to the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Ken -- is a 3rd Party Solution allowed in an _Answer_?  I couldn't see any rules against it.  I figure this is a very interesting question, and rubberduckvba.com looks like an excellent (free) solution...

Comment: @ashleedawg: No, answers consisting of nothing but a link off-site are not appropriate here. This is covered in the [help] pages. Answers should contain enough content to be self-sustaining, with external links only used for additional reference material. If the link is unavailable in the future, the answer should stand on its own. That clearly wouldn't be the case with the URL referenced in your comment; a comment is the appropriate place to provide it, not an answer.